# Separating columns using regex in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a data set where the columns are separated using a ton of white space, so that when you open it in a text editor, the columns are aligned.

The problem is that I can't open this file using the white space separator, because one of the columns contain sentences that have spaces. I was wondering if I could somehow open this file in `R`, by making a regex separator,

like `\s{2,}`.

I've tried typing `sep='\s{2,}'`

but that doesn't work.

Comment: you can read your file with readLines and then seperate the elements with strsplit and then aggregate your data in a data.frame but it would be tiresome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `readLines` to read all lines and `strsplit`+`rbind` to create your `data.frame` afterwards:

```
ll <- readLines(
  textConnection("Column1          Column2
Stupid sentence  Stupid sentence 2
foobar           foobar 2"))

l <- strsplit(ll, " {2,}")

df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, l[-1]))
colnames(df) <- l[[1]]
df
#          Column1           Column2
#1 Stupid sentence Stupid sentence 2
#2          foobar          foobar 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the white spaces for the columns data by regex

Comment: I've tried doing this with Sublime Text, but the text file is pretty big and it crashes.